# Using the realtime FourSquare API without the need for an app?

Tags: foursquare

Note this page: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime

It suggests that we can configure a HTTP POST (containing json) to an url of our choice when users checkin at one of our venues.

Our 160+ venues are recorded under this business account: https://foursquare.com/cohenschem

We want these HTTP POST's making to an url on our webserver ([https://www.cohenschemist.co.uk/](https://www.cohenschemist.co.uk)).
We're fine parsing the json - that's the easy bit, what we don't understand however is how to go about setting up the http posts themselves? The 1st link suggests the creation of application (???) - it refers to a "consumer" & suggests logging in at https://foursquare.com/developers/apps and "Click on your consumers name" - when we login at developers/apps - we don't see any "consumers" listed to click on? We're not even sure what a "Consumer" actually is?? Are we going about this all wrong?

We don't have an ios / android app or anything like that, we just want the simple json posts sending to our webserver when someone checks in at one of our venues - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly possible! The language on the developer site sometimes interchangeably uses "consumer" an "app" to refer to an applications—sorry for the confusion. To get started, you need to first create an app or consumer on https://foursquare.com/developers/apps (you must be logged in with your Foursquare account). Fill in details (the redirect URI and push URI are really the only important ones) and create a new app that receives checkins at venues managed by your app's users.

After you create your new app, [authenticate](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) your app as your chain. You should now be getting POSTs from Foursquare upon each check-in at your managed venues.

Comment: Do we create the "App" as our personal account or business account? Would the "App" in our case be the public facing site that we want the push notifications to be sent to? You say "your app's users" - we don't have an "App" persay. They would just be using the native FourSquare app? Is this still possible?

Comment: You can create the app using any account—I recommend your business account so it's not tied to any personal data. Your "app"'s user will actually be the cohenschem user on Foursquare. Once this user has authenticated your app, you will start getting POSTs from Foursquare at the URI you specified.

Comment: Again, "app" is interchangeable with "API consumer." You don't need a public-facing website or mobile app or whatnot :) You will see pushes from whoever checks into a location managed by cohenschem